# How do I edit a user's info in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, crud

I have built a small and simple rails app that I deployed on heroku where you have to sign up as a user by creating a profile, after which you can enter an address or zipcode to find the nearest gyms in your vicinity, which triggers the google places/geocoder api and brings you some results. 
My issue is that in trying to CRUD my app, I can't get the U, basically the update to work. I'll paste my code below and as you'll see I put a binding.pry and tested it directly in the rails console to see if my code is right and it works, I'm able to edit a user's info which is then updated when I go into psql and look in my db. But trying to use the browser to make the update does not work.

This is in my users_controller.rb file:

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
     # binding.pry
@user.update(name: params[:name],  password: params[:password], email: params[:email], zipcode: params[:zipcode])
redirect_to '/users'
```

end

```
This is the template code:
<h4 id="edit"> Edit your profile below: </h4>

<form action="/users/<%= @user.id%>" method="POST">
  <div id="label">

<label>
      <input id="one" name="name" placeholder="Edit name"/>
    </label>

        <label>
        <input id="two" name="email" placeholder="Edit email"/>
      </label>

      <br>
      <br>

      <label>
      <input id="three" name="password" placeholder="Edit password"/>
      </label>

    <label>
      <input id="four" name="zipcode" placeholder="Edit zipcode"/>
    </label>
    </div>

     <input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden" />
   <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token()%>" type="hidden">
   <div id="update">
    <br>
 <button id="update">Update your profile</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The routes work and I'm taken to a confirmation page that I set up, but when I try to login with my updated info, the old info is still persistent. No errors are shown either that stop me from doing anything in the app. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

I see these errors in my terminal:

## , @messages={:email=>["Not a valid email format"]}>

## , @messages={:email=>["Not a valid email format"]}>

Comment: Add 'logger.debug(@users.errors.inspect)' after your @user.update (no quotes). What does it say in the server console?

Comment: I added what u said and it says undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
In the rails console when I did it before to test, everything worked, I'm able to edit user info, but when I do it in the browser, no such luck.

Comment: I think u meant to write, @user instead. I just did logger.debug(@user.error.inspect) and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** I used the advice of RichadAE and looked into the logs of my terminal to see the error messages and I saw that one of the errors was that when I was updating my user info, I was just updating the name or the zip for testing purposes which is fine, but because I am using the gem 'validates_email_format_of' the email field cannot be left blank even when updating otherwise it breaks my code, I tried to edit the name and filled in the email input field to meet the requirement and it worked!!! Thank you for your help!!